# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable functionn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I call a composable function from context of corrutines?
I trying the following code but I getting the error.

```
@Composable
    fun ShowItems(){
        var ListArticle = ArrayList<Article>()
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            // Triggers the flow and starts listening for values
            viewModel.uiState.collect { uiState ->
                // New value received
                when (uiState) {
                    is MainViewModel.LatestNewsUiState.Success -> {
                        //Log.e(TAG,"${uiState.news}")
                        if(uiState.news != null){
                            for(i in uiState.news){
                                ListArticle.add(i)
                            }
                            context.ItemNews(uiState.news.get(4))
                            Log.e(TAG,"${uiState.news}")
                        }
                    }
                    is MainViewModel.LatestNewsUiState.Error -> Log.e(TAG,"${uiState.exception}")
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Most likely, your coroutine should be updating some `State` that your composables react to.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ShowItems(){
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    // Mount your UI in according to uiState object
    when (uiState.value) {
       is MainViewModel.LatestNewsUiState.Success -> { ... }
       is MainViewModel.LatestNewsUiState.Error -> { ... }
    }
    // Launch a coroutine when the component is first launched
    LaunchedEffect(viewModel) {
        // this call should change uiState internally in your viewModel
        viewModel.loadYourData() 
    }
}
```